# Transpiling in Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I added

### Babel Preset ENV

as well as `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` to my plugins to make it work, everything works fine now, however it still wont load in ie11, can't figure out why?

webpack.config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const pkg = require('./package.json');
const path = require('path');

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod';

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'sourc-emap',
  entry: {
    app: `${pkg.paths.src.js}index.js`,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname) + pkg.paths.src.assets,
    filename: '[name].bundle.min.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: debug
    ? [
    ]
    : [
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
      // new webpack2.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }),
    ],
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015"],
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7", "ie 10-11"]
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports"
  ]
}
```

my entry index.js:

```
const jsLoader = document.querySelector('.js-loader');

if (jsLoader) {
  import('./modules/loader.js')
    .then(module => module.loader);
}
```

and the module loader.js

```
const jsLoader = document.querySelector('.js-loader');
// hide loader on pageload
window.onload = function init() {
  jsLoader.style.display = 'none';
};

export default jsLoader;
```

its just a simple loader that should be hidden after the page loaded, only to figure out if it works in older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i figured that i don't have to use a babel loader for transpiling the es2015 code since webpack 2 will do it

webpack 2 *does* support the es2015 *module* syntax, and webpack 2 can successfully *parse* the es2015 language features out of the box. However, this does not guarantee your browser will, nor will webpack *transform* the module features.

### Babel Preset ENV

In a situation like this, we recommend you use the the babel preset `babel-preset-env`. This will allow you to specify which browsers you are looking to support, and then subsequently leverage babel and babel-loader to only transpile the changes that are not natively supported.

Comment: Hey Sean, thanks a lot, i installed the Preset "env" but somehow its still not working , i updated my post above.

Comment: You can set debug: true to find out which plugins/syntaxes/transforms are being used. Also what error on IE11 are you seeing. Is this maybe because of a lacking promise's polyfill?

Comment: it doesn't throw out any console error, it just wont set the loader to display=none as it does in edge, chrome, safari etc ...i will try to add the polyfill plugin ..thanks sean